# Deploy GitLab web app to Azure app service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, gitlab

Hello guys am new with Gitlab and Azure , currently am having a repo on Gitlba and am trying to deploy it to Azure, but I can't manage to achieve this, tried to follow this [link](https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/auto-deploying-to-azure-app-services-from-gitlab/) , but the information is old, Is there anyone with a latest link or resource to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment and https://blog.brooksjc.com/2018/12/27/gitlab-continuous-ci-cd-with-an-azure-web-app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI of the azure portal and the GitLab have changed, but the steps are still similar.

The [link](https://blog.brooksjc.com/2018/12/27/gitlab-continuous-ci-cd-with-an-azure-web-app/) in the comment is helpful, I test it and works fine.
In order to prevent the link from failing in the future, I made some summary as below.

1.In the web app in the portal -> `Deployment Center` ->  `External`  -> `App Service build service` -> write the information as below -> next to finish.

[image]

The `Repository` you can get via the `Clone` button in your GitLab project, the `Username` and `Password` is the ones of your GitLab account.

[image]

2.In your GitLab -> `Settings` -> `Repository` -> `Deploy Keys` -> `Expand` -> Add the key of the one in the `https://<webapp-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/sshkey?ensurePublicKey=1`(`ssh-rsa xxxxxx`). Then you could test the `Sync` in the `Deployment Center` in the portal, it should work.

3.Then we config the continuous deployment, in your GitLab -> `Settings` -> `Integrations` -> write the `URL` ( you can get it in the web app -> `Properties` -> `Deployment Trigger URL` ) -> `Add webhook`.

4.Then I create a new file in the GitLab project, it deploys to the web app automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Joy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9455659/joy-wang)'s [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57653339/9831274) is helpful. I've rewritten it to clarify the steps on obtaining a SSH 'deploy key'.

1. Head over to your Gitlab repository and click the *Clone* button. Copy the *Clone with SSH* address.

   [image: Gitlab Repository Clone Button]

   Also, have your Gitlab account username and password available.
2. In the Azure portal go to your web app resource and go to the *Deployment Center*. Choose the *External* option. We're going to use the 'App Service build service'. Next enter in the data from step 1. Click *Continue* to finish.

   [image: Enter the data from step 1]
3. Next we're going to get the SSH 'deploy key'.

   1. First go to the *Properties* page and copy the *Deployment Trigger Url* field.
   2. Go back to the *Deployment Center* and click the *Credentials* button.
   3. Insert these credentials into your copied url, like so:
      `https://$mysite:BigRandomPassword@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/deploy`
   4. Take the full deploy URL above, and replace `/deploy` with `/api/sshkey?ensurePublicKey=1`. So it'll look like:
      `https://$mysite:BigRandomPassword@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/sshkey?ensurePublicKey=1`
   5. Run curl on this URL, which returns an SSH public key. It's returned as a JSON string, so you'll need to remove the quotes. It should look like:
      `ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1etc...`
      Copy the key.

   (*These steps are from the [Kudu docs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment#setting-up-continuous-deployment-using-manual-steps)*)
4. In GitLab go to *Settings* -> *Repository* -> *Deploy Keys* and click  *Expand*. Add a title and the SSH 'deploy key' here. Then save. Test it by going back to the *Deployment Center* in the Azure portal and clicking the *Sync* button. It should work.

   [image: Adding deploy key to Gitlab]
5. Then we'll configure the continuous deployment. In your GitLab go to  *Settings* -> *Integrations* -> write the *URL* (This is the same *Deployment Trigger URL* in *Properties* we used earlier) To save click the *Add webhook* button.

   [image: Add Gitlab Integration]
6. Create a new file (or commit a change) in the GitLab project and it deploys to the web app automatically.

Comment: "Deploying with SSH and a private repository is not supported." The error it shows now.

Comment: @TanveerBadar is it still not supported? The only possibility would be to make the repo public?